# How to filter Pandas data table using two fields in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data table :

```
    File_name     River  Confidance     X     Y     W     H  T_Area  Overlap_Area
0   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.587851   739   821   769   894       0           0.0
1   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.579243   980   286  1018   361       0           0.0
2   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.534472   966   935  1038   973    1406         296.0
3   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.530194   275   859   313   934       0           0.0
4   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.368075   944   516   976   589       0           0.0
5   test1.png  BRIDGING    0.132732   929   814  1000   856    1640        1240.0
6   test2.png  BRIDGING    0.748589   886  1199   963  1248       0           0.0
7   test4.png  BRIDGING    0.594574   147  1390   224  1456       0           0.0
8   test4.png  BRIDGING    0.149411   150  1701   221  1732       0           0.0
9   test4.png  BRIDGING    0.145715  1385  1245  1462  1279       0           0.0
10  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.133226  1385  1049  1463  1084     100        1645.0
```

I want to find the records where `"T_Area" == 0` or `"T_Area" / "Overlap_Area" > 0.5` using `groupby` in pandas.

Item 10 should be dropped in the output since `100 / 1645 < 0.5`

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: `Area == 0` - it means both columns `T_Area/Overlap_Area` ? Or there is some column `Area` not exist in sample data?

Comment: Its "T Area". Corected in the question.

Comment: And what means `groupby` ?

Comment: Can you answer to the question of @jezrael. Why `groupby`? Do you want to drop all rows where filename is "test4.png"?

Comment: @Corralien - only way is removed group if match, like your answer I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[df['T Area'].eq(0) | df['T Area'].div(df['Overlap Area']).gt(0.5)]
```

Output:

```
   File_name     River  Confidance     X     Y     W     H  T_Area  Overlap_Area
0  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.587851   739   821   769   894       0           0.0
1  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.579243   980   286  1018   361       0           0.0
2  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.534472   966   935  1038   973    1406         296.0
3  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.530194   275   859   313   934       0           0.0
4  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.368075   944   516   976   589       0           0.0
5  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.132732   929   814  1000   856    1640        1240.0
6  test2.png  BRIDGING    0.748589   886  1199   963  1248       0           0.0
7  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.594574   147  1390   224  1456       0           0.0
8  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.149411   150  1701   221  1732       0           0.0
9  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.145715  1385  1245  1462  1279       0           0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
m1 = df['T Area'] == 0
m2 = df['T Area'] / df['Overlap Area'] > 0.5
out = df[m1 | m2]
print(out)

# Output
   File name     River  Confidance     X     Y     W     H  T Area  Overlap Area
0  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.587851   739   821   769   894       0           0.0
1  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.579243   980   286  1018   361       0           0.0
2  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.534472   966   935  1038   973    1406         296.0
3  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.530194   275   859   313   934       0           0.0
4  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.368075   944   516   976   589       0           0.0
5  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.132732   929   814  1000   856    1640        1240.0
6  test2.png  BRIDGING    0.748589   886  1199   963  1248       0           0.0
7  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.594574   147  1390   224  1456       0           0.0
8  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.149411   150  1701   221  1732       0           0.0
9  test4.png  BRIDGING    0.145715  1385  1245  1462  1279       0           0.0
```

**Update**

If you want to remove all rows from a group (file name) where at least one row violate the conditions, use `groupby_transform`:

```
out = df[(m1 | m2).groupby(df['File name']).transform(min)]
print(out)

# Output
   File name     River  Confidance    X     Y     W     H  T Area  Overlap Area
0  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.587851  739   821   769   894       0           0.0
1  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.579243  980   286  1018   361       0           0.0
2  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.534472  966   935  1038   973    1406         296.0
3  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.530194  275   859   313   934       0           0.0
4  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.368075  944   516   976   589       0           0.0
5  test1.png  BRIDGING    0.132732  929   814  1000   856    1640        1240.0
6  test2.png  BRIDGING    0.748589  886  1199   963  1248       0           0.0
```

Comment: I like this method, and this is my first time seeing this. But this one does not do any filtering. Always False for the last column regardless of the m1 and m2.

Comment: The bug is in the first or second approach?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
df.groupby(['File_name']).apply(lambda x: x[(x['T_Area']/x['Overlap_Area']>0.5) | (x['T_Area']==0)])
```

Comment: This is harder to read, at least to me . . . but not sure about the speed